# How to set post-commit script in SVN to update modified files?

Tags: svn, post-commit, post-commit-hook

I deleted post-commit.tmpl, and in post-commit file, here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8   
SVN_Path=/root/svn/myblog
WEB_Path=/home/app/myblog
echo `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
$SVN_Path update --username xxx --password yyy $WEB_Path --no-auth-cache 

# POST-COMMIT HOOK
#
# The post-commit hook is invoked after a commit.  Subversion runs
# this hook by invoking a program (script, executable, binary, etc.)
# named 'post-commit' (for which this file is a template) with the 
# following ordered arguments:
#
#   [1] REPOS-PATH   (the path to this repository)
#   [2] REV          (the number of the revision just committed)
#
# The default working directory for the invocation is undefined, so
# the program should set one explicitly if it cares.
#
# Because the commit has already completed and cannot be undone,
# the exit code of the hook program is ignored.  The hook program
# can use the 'svnlook' utility to help it examine the
# newly-committed tree.
#
# On a Unix system, the normal procedure is to have 'post-commit'
# invoke other programs to do the real work, though it may do the
# work itself too.
#
# Note that 'post-commit' must be executable by the user(s) who will
# invoke it (typically the user httpd runs as), and that user must
# have filesystem-level permission to access the repository.
#
# On a Windows system, you should name the hook program
# 'post-commit.bat' or 'post-commit.exe',
# but the basic idea is the same.
# 
# The hook program typically does not inherit the environment of
# its parent process.  For example, a common problem is for the
# PATH environment variable to not be set to its usual value, so
# that subprograms fail to launch unless invoked via absolute path.
# If you're having unexpected problems with a hook program, the
# culprit may be unusual (or missing) environment variables.
# 
# Here is an example hook script, for a Unix /bin/sh interpreter.
# For more examples and pre-written hooks, see those in
# the Subversion repository at
# http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/ and
# http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/

# REPOS="$1"
# REV="$2"

# mailer.py commit "$REPOS" "$REV" /path/to/mailer.conf
```

Unfortunately, nothing will happen in my project file (project path is /home/app/myblog) after I commit my modified code to server. But if I execute this file in command line, I will get this info:

```
 2016-11-09 16:32:10
./post-commit: line 9: /root/svn/myblog: Is a directory
```

Meanwhile, in the follow path: /root/svn/myblog/db/revprops/0, I can find all commit log files. I guess it means the modified files are committed to server, right?

I am using CentOS, Express.

So, could anyone help me about this? Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

> `2016-11-09 16:32:10 ./post-commit: line 9: /root/svn/myblog: Is a
>   directory`

According to the code, `$SVN_Path` should point to the Subversion command-line client `svn`. But it points to a directory `/myblog`, instead:

`SVN_Path=/root/svn/myblog`

You should adjust `$SVN_Path` to point to `svn` client on the computer.

> Meanwhile, in the follow path: /root/svn/myblog/db/revprops/0, I can
>   find all commit log files. I guess it means the modified files are
>   committed to server, right?

Post-commit hooks run *after* the commit is made. So, yes, the commit made it to the repository. However, the hook didn't run because of the typo in `$SVN_Path`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modified $SVN_PATH, and restart svn on server, but nothing changed. I committed and no update in project path. And I tried to execute modified post-commit script in command line, I still get this: ./post-commit: line 9: /root/svn: Is a directory. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: @HenryYong the path is still invalid. `/root/svn` is not an executable. Find the actual path to `svn` on your system: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28555/how-to-find-applications-path-from-command-line

Comment: I have found the actual path, which is /usr/bin/svn. But it still doesn't work. In command line, I got this now: Skipped '/home/app/myblog'
Summary of conflicts:  Skipped paths: 1